# How do I compile the C perfect minimal hashing library on windows?

Tags: c, windows, makefile, configure

I've installed mingw and Msys.

I've run `bash configure` to create the make file.

But when I run `make` I get the following output

```
E:\cmph-1.1>make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/e/cmph-1.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/e/cmph-1.1/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -Wall -Werror -MT hash.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hash.Tpo -c -o hash.lo hash.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT hash.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hash.Tpo -c hash.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/hash.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT hash.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hash.Tpo -c hash.c -o hash.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/hash.Tpo .deps/hash.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -Wall -Werror -MT jenkins_hash.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/jenkins_hash.Tpo -c -o jenkins_hash.lo jenkins_hash.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT jenkins_hash.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/jenkins_hash.Tpo -c jenkins_hash.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/jenkins_hash.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT jenkins_hash.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/jenkins_hash.Tpo -c jenkins_hash.c -o jenkins_hash.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/jenkins_hash.Tpo .deps/jenkins_hash.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -Wall -Werror -MT vstack.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vstack.Tpo -c -o vstack.lo vstack.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT vstack.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vstack.Tpo -c vstack.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/vstack.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT vstack.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vstack.Tpo -c vstack.c -o vstack.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/vstack.Tpo .deps/vstack.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -Wall -Werror -MT vqueue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vqueue.Tpo -c -o vqueue.lo vqueue.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT vqueue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vqueue.Tpo -c vqueue.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/vqueue.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT vqueue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vqueue.Tpo -c vqueue.c -o vqueue.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/vqueue.Tpo .deps/vqueue.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -Wall -Werror -MT graph.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/graph.Tpo -c -o graph.lo graph.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT graph.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/graph.Tpo -c graph.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/graph.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT graph.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/graph.Tpo -c graph.c -o graph.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/graph.Tpo .deps/graph.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -Wall -Werror -MT cmph.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/cmph.Tpo -c -o cmph.lo cmph.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Werror -MT cmph.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/cmph.Tpo -c cmph.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/cmph.o
In file included from cmph.h:105:0,
                 from cmph.c:1:
cmph_time.h: In function 'elapsed_time_in_seconds':
cmph_time.h:23:19: error: storage size of 'e_time' isn't known
cmph_time.h:24:4: error: implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cmph_time.h:23:19: error: unused variable 'e_time' [-Werror=unused-variable]
cmph_time.h: In function 'elapsed_time_in_useconds':
cmph_time.h:34:19: error: storage size of 'e_time' isn't known
cmph_time.h:34:19: error: unused variable 'e_time' [-Werror=unused-variable]
cmph.c: In function 'count_nlfile_keys':
cmph.c:154:18: error: variable 'ptr' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I'm struggling to work out what I need to do to make it compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in that that header file, you'll see near the top this construct:

```
#ifdef WIN32
// include headers to use gettimeofday
#else
    #ifdef __GNUC__
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <sys/resource.h>
    #endif
#endif
```

It looks like you're not ending up in that second half, from where you'd get the declarations  of `gettimeofday()` and `struct timeval`.

I'm not very familiar with MinGW - does it define `WIN32`?  If so, you might need to rework that preprocessor logic to do what you want.  For reference, it works fine in cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this patch that contains the fix to compile on mingw : http://sourceforge.net/p/cmph/patches/3/